# WebRTC streams freeze after first frame

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video-streaming, webrtc, chromium

Here's the deal, I've got a WebRTC 1 on 1 conversation using:

- [SimpleWebRTC library](https://simplewebrtc.com/)
- [CoTurn server](https://code.google.com/p/coturn/)
- [Signaling server](https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster)

Everything seems to work fine, but there is one problem:

Chrom* browsers display only first frame of the video and then the video freezes, as well as audio. Looking at the Chromium process network and CPU usage, it's getting and decoding video, but not showing it. Here are my codes:

```
window.webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
    localVideoEl: 'local',
    remoteVideosEl: 'remote',
    autoRequestMedia: true,
    debug: true,
    url: 'https://server.server:8888/'
});

window.webrtc.on('videoAdded', function (video, peer) {
    var remotes = document.getElementById('remote');
    if (remotes) {
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        container.className = 'videoContainer';
        container.id = 'container_' + webrtc.getDomId(peer);
        container.appendChild(video);

        video.oncontextmenu = function () {
            return false;
        };

        remotes.appendChild(container);

        if (peer) {
            peer.on('iceConnectionStateChange', function (event) {
                switch (peer.pc.iceConnectionState) {
                    case 'checking':
                        $('#status').text('Connecting...');
                        break;
                    case 'connected':
                    case 'completed': // on caller side
                        $('#status').text('Connected');
                        break;
                    case 'disconnected':
                        $('#status').text('Disconnected');
                        break;
                    case 'failed':
                        $('#status').text('Failed to connect');
                        break;
                    case 'closed':
                        $('#status').text('Connection closed');
                        $('#remote').empty();
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

window.webrtc.on('readyToCall', $.ajax({
    url: '/getroom.php',
    success: function (data) {
        window.webrtc.joinRoom(data);
    }
}));
```

```
<p id="status">Waiting...</p>
<video id="local" width="300" height="225" autoplay></video>
<div id="remote"></div>
```

Signalmaster:

```
{
    "uid": "nobody",
    "isDev": true,
    "logLevel": 3,
    "server": {
            "port": 8888,
            "secure": true,
            "key": "key.key",
            "cert": "cer.cer"
    },
    "stunservers" : [
            {
                    "url": "stun:server.server:3478"
            }
    ],
    "turnservers" : [
            {
                    "url": "turn:server.server:3478",
                    "secret": "qgJeuJuIyeqX",
                    "expiry": 86400
            }
    ]
}
```

CoTurn server is configured to `qgJeuJuIyeqX` secret key and to `server.server` realm, everything else is default.

Comment: Apperently, videoAdded method was a problem, after removing it and letting SimpleWebRTC handle the video adds, it was fixed, but this isn't the proper answer to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be an issue in Chrome where re-appending video elements causes the video to freeze. The solution is to only add the video element once. I got around this by leaving the remoteVideosEl section blank:

```
window.webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
    localVideoEl: 'local',
    remoteVideosEl: '',
    autoRequestMedia: true,
    debug: true,
    url: 'https://server.server:8888/'
});
```

This way SimpleWebRTC does not automatically attach the video element for you, so when the 'videoAdded' method is called you can attach the video for the first time.

Comment: What is the equivalent of the 'remoteVideosEl' parameter  if one is using  just RTCPeerConnection and not SimpleWebRTC? It looks like SimpleWebRTC is a paid service.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to call .play() for DOM element, so it will start video/audio transmit. To avoid exception in console, you can use this hotfix: [How to prevent "The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803176/how-to-prevent-the-play-request-was-interrupted-by-a-call-to-pause-error)