# Video Player error Uncaught in promise DOMException

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have [Video Player](http://viblog.apyazilim.com/videopage.html). But when I change the quality its giving this error

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted
>   by a call to pause().

**JavaScript**

```
e(".ad-quality-option").on("click", function() {
    w.pause()
    var t = e(this).html();
    e(".ad-quality-dropdown").fadeOut(fade), 
        e(".ad-quality-menu").html(t);
    var a = e(this).attr("data-quality");
    w.src = a,
        w.addEventListener("canplay",  function() {    
        w.currentTime=e(".ad-video").attr("data-current"),w.play() });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a race condition between 2 promises. same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803176/how-to-prevent-the-play-request-was-interrupted-by-a-call-to-pause-error).

If you use video player by default and don't have "src" attribute, this issue occurs.