# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request. [by a call to pause().]

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

At the begining I have an error:

1) `video.js:91Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.`

2) I've tried to google and found this:

```
$("#myVideo").get(0).play();
```

3) And now I have theese errors:
a) On the [main page](http://kulseitov.kz/relog/) of landing page where is video is placed.

```
video.js:91Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.
```

б) On the other pages [for example](http://kulseitov.kz/relog/plans.html) where is video is missing

```
scripts.js:28Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code please?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803176/how-to-prevent-the-play-request-was-interrupted-by-a-call-to-pause-error

Comment: @Rayon Please read a question )) I fixed error "[by a call to pause().]" I have another two errors which is described in my question =)