# dynamically changing video gives the play() request was interrupted by a new load request

Tags: javascript

When dynamically changing the video , i am getting the following error under server console

```
(index):71 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.
```

I am using the following code when change occurred

```
function playlocalVID()
{
        var player = document.getElementById("video");
        var currentVID = document.getElementById('currentVID');
        var selectedLocalVID = document.getElementById('howtovideo').files[0];
        currentVID.setAttribute('src', URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([selectedLocalVID])));
        player.load();
        player.play();
}
```

But when changed the video 3 - 4 times or clicked on Remove Button

i am getting the issue

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.
```

This is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/q3hhk17e/36/

Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue .

Comment: could you please let me know what do you mean by bootstrap in this context ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803176/how-to-prevent-the-play-request-was-interrupted-by-a-call-to-pause-error

Comment: what function is called with remove button ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attach `canplay` event to `#video` element, within `playlocalVID()` call create `Blob URL` from `File` object, note it is not necessary to also call `Blob()` with `File` object as parameter; set current `File.name` at `#video` `.dataset`; set `<input type="file">` element `.value` to `null` for `change` event to be called when same file is selected in succession; call `.load()` at `#video` element; wait for `canplay` or `canplaythrough` event to be dispatched at `#video` element; at `canplay` event handler call `.play()` at `#video` element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-group last">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">How to video</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
        <figure>
          <video id="video" width="150" height="100" controls>
            <source id='currentVID' src="" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
          <figcaption></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"></div>
        <div>
          <span class="btn default btn-file">
            <span class="fileinput-new"> Select Video </span>
          <span class="fileinput-exists"> Change </span>
          <input type="file" id="howtovideo" name="howtovideo" accept="video/mp4" autoplay onchange="playlocalVID();" />
          </span>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn red fileinput-exists removepic" data-name="removeforhowtovideo" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var player = document.getElementById("video");
    var currentVID = document.getElementById('currentVID');
    var caption = document.querySelector("figcaption");
    var selectedLocalVID = document.getElementById("howtovideo");
     // reference to `Blob URL` to be created at `playLocalVID`
    var url;
     // attach `canplay` event to `player`
    player.addEventListener("canplay", function handleEvent(e) {
      this.play();
      // set `figcaption` to current video `File.name`
      caption.innerHTML = this.dataset.currentVideo;
    });

    function playlocalVID() {
      if (url) {
        console.log(url);
        // if `url` is defined revoke existing `Blob URL`
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }
      // create `Blob URL` of `File` object
      url = URL.createObjectURL(selectedLocalVID.files[0]);
      // set `.name` of current `File` at `player.dataset.currentVideo`
      player.dataset.currentVideo = selectedLocalVID.files[0].name;
      // reset `input type="file"` event
      selectedLocalVID.value = null;
      // call `.pause()` at `player`
      player.pause();
      // set new `src` at `<source>` element
      currentVID.setAttribute("src", url);
      // call `.load()` on `player`
      // wait for `canplay` event
      player.load();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Kinda messy, but it worked for me. (the important part is just: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/331#issuecomment-529398384)