# multiple html5 audio elements Jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I've written some Jquery code that plays a sound when a div is clicked for multiple audio elements. The code seems to work (probably not in the most sophisticated way) but I'm getting the following error in the console.

"app.js:152 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request."

I'm just wondering what potential problems this could cause and any pointers on how to get rid of this error?

JS

```
$('.speaker').on("click", function() {
    var speakertriggered = $(this);
    var speakerdata = speakertriggered.data('speaker');
    var audioelement = $('#' + speakerdata);
    var getaudio = $(audioelement)[0];

    $(speakertriggered).addClass('speakerplay');
    getaudio.load();
    getaudio.play();

    $(audioelement).on('ended', function() {
        $(speakertriggered).removeClass('speakerplay');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="speaker" data-speaker="left-player"></div>

<audio id="left-player">
    <source src="assets/sounds/left.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    <source src="assets/sounds/left.mp3" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>



<div class="speaker" data-speaker="right-player"></div>

<audio id="right-player">
    <source src="assets/sounds/right.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    <source src="assets/sounds/right.mp3" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `.pause()` before calling `.load()` and `.play()`, see [dynamically changing video gives the play() request was interrupted by a new load request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234873/dynamically-changing-video-gives-the-play-request-was-interrupted-by-a-new-loa/40355228#40355228)