# HTML5 audio tag doesn't play some audio

Tags: javascript, audio, ipc, electron, webtorrent

I'm building a music player with electron. In the main proccess I have all the events an content management, and I load music in renderer by http server create in the main, so the `audio` tag have the `src` atribute like `src = http://localhost:9999`. The songs are downloaded from torrent with webtorrent. My problem is that wen I change the current torrent in play, for example from 1st torrent in download to 2nd torrent, because the 1st torrent doesn't have more content to play, and I init the new server with new content and try to play the sound the audio doesn't start but log on the main proccess say that audio is loaded on the http server. Also if I manually click on other song of this 2nd torrent the audio works well but I get the following error on console:
`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()`

The function that set the audio tag src is:

```
ipc.on('toPlay', (event, data) => {
    console.log('http://localhost:9999/' + data[0].toString());

    audio_tag.src = 'http://localhost:9999/' + data[0].toString();
    play = true;

    audio_tag.play();


    audio_tag.onended = function(){
    console.log('play end, to play ' + (data[0]+1).toString() + 'from torrent number: ' + data[1].toString());
    ipc.send('getPlayData', [data[0]+1, data[1]]); 
    }
})
```

where `data[0]` represents the index of file in the torrent, because the full url is `http://localhost:9999/<index of file>`

And the main proccess send send the ipc message like this:

```
ipc.on('getPlayData', function(event, data) {
    var torrent = data[1];
    var file = data[0];


    if((file <= downloaderInstance.getTorrentFiles(torrent).length) && (downloaderInstance.getTorrentFiles(torrent)[file].name.indexOf('mp3') != -1)){
    var i = file;
    while(downloaderInstance.getTorrentFiles(torrent)[i].name.indexOf('mp3') == -1 &&
         file <= downloaderInstance.getTorrentFiles(torrent).length){
        file++;
    }
    } else {
    torrent++;
    }

    if(torrent <= downloaderInstance.getNTorrents() && torrent != data[1]){
    file = 0;
    while(downloaderInstance.getTorrentFiles(torrent)[file].name.indexOf('mp3') == -1 &&
          file <= downloaderInstance.getTorrentFiles(torrent).length){
        file++;
    }
    } else if (torrent >= downloaderInstance.getNTorrents() && torrent != data[1]){
    torrent = 0;
    file = 0;
    while(downloaderInstance.getTorrentFiles(torrent)[file].name.indexOf('mp3') == -1 &&
          file <= downloaderInstance.getTorrentFiles(torrent).length){
        file++;
    }
    }   

    if(torrent != currentPlayingTorrent){
    currentPlayingTorrent = torrent;
    if(currentPlayingTorrent != undefined)
        downloaderInstance.closeTorrentServer();

    downloaderInstance.initTorrentServer(currentPlayingTorrent);
    downloaderInstance.listen();
    }

    console.log(file + ' ' + torrent);
    console.log('toplay ' + file.toString() + '(' + downloaderInstance.getTorrentFiles(torrent)[file].name + ')' + ' from ' + torrent.toString());
    event.sender.send('toPlay', [file, torrent]);
})
```

The error only ocurs in the change of torrent, and I try 100 forms to solve it with no solution.

Any idea why it's happening?

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE

I found something based off of your error:

> `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()`

It's race condition between [`play()` and `pause()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36898221/2813224)

Try:

```
var waitTime = 150;

setTimeout(function () {      
  if (el.paused) {
    el.play();
  }
}, waitTime);
```

---

#### OLD

When changing `src` of an audio or video tag, you have to invoke the `.load()` method before the `.play()` method. The change is applied and commented in the Snippet below. Not tested for your circumstances of course.

#### SNIPPET

```js
ipc.on('toPlay', (event, data) => {
  console.log('http://localhost:9999/' + data[0].toString());

  audio_tag.src = 'http://localhost:9999/' + data[0].toString();
  play = true;

  //  .load() needs to be right before .play()
  /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
  audio_tag.load();
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
  audio_tag.play();


  audio_tag.onended = function() {
    console.log('play end, to play ' + (data[0] + 1).toString() + 'from torrent number: ' + data[1].toString());
    ipc.send('getPlayData', [data[0] + 1, data[1]]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I still have the same result after apply your changes also I have a `console.log` message after the load request, and it doesn't appear in the console. I hope this ino helps for more possible respondes. @zer00one

Comment: Hi @rafaelleru do you use an audio tag or or object (`new Audio`)? `toPlay` is a custom event?

Comment: audio tag @zer00ne

Comment: I didn't notice the code for the custom event: `toPlay`, is posted?

Comment: is the ipc message identifier @zer00ne

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129288/discussion-between-zer00ne-and-rafaelleru).