# Javascript Parser error

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have a HTML5 video that has a poster and a CSS play overlay button. I am trying to get the video to load once it has ended so that it shows the poster and the play overlay button again.

I have tried the following code but get a Parser error on the last line, can anybody help me and let me know what it is I am doing wrong!?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.video').parent().click(function () {
    if ($(this).children(".video").get(0).paused) {
      $(this).children(".video").get(0).play();
      $(this).children(".playpause").fadeOut();
    } else {
      $(this).children(".video").get(0).pause();
      $(this).children(".playpause").fadeIn();
    }
  });

  var video= $(".video").get(0);   
  video.addEventListener('ended',function () {
    video.load(); 
    $(".playpause").show();                              
  }, false);
});
```

Comment: And the exact error message is...?

Comment: Can't see an error. It would help if you properly indented the code.

Comment: Would help if you add the HTML too.

Comment: The code does not cause any errors for me, probably because none of the appropriate conditions or callbacks are executing. In your browser try drilling down/clicking on the error. Use Firebug or Chrome dev tools to see the exact source of the error message.

Comment: @j08691 This is the error `undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().` . To reproduce wait until video has completed, then immediately click `"click"` twice in rapid succession https://jsfiddle.net/q1wnLwa3/1/

Answer (score 1):

To prevent

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().
```

error, wrap `if` statement within `click` handler within `setTimeout()` call.

See also [How to prevent "The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803176/how-to-prevent-the-play-request-was-interrupted-by-a-call-to-pause-error)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.video').parent().click(function () {
    var vid = $(this).children(".video").get(0);
    setTimeout(function() {
    if (vid.paused) {
      vid.play();
      $(this).children(".playpause").fadeOut();
    } else {
      vid.pause();
      $(this).children(".playpause").fadeIn();
    }
    })
  });

  var video= $(".video").get(0);   
  video.addEventListener('ended',function () {
    video.load(); 
    $(".playpause").show();                              
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
click<br>
<span class="playpause">play pause</span>
<video controls class="video" poster="https://placehold.it/350x150"  src="https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4"></video>
</div>
```