# Uncaught DOM exception with HTMLVideoElement

Tags: javascript, html, chromium

While creating a video player, I caught this shizzle:
[image]

And the main fact is: (by the way I'm using OS X Sierra) it happens only in Chromium browser after switching to other desktop. No such issue in Chrome, Opera, Safari and even Firefox (Firefox is very problematic about these things). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below link it have some description for the issue you are facing.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=593273

And this:
[How to prevent "The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803176/how-to-prevent-the-play-request-was-interrupted-by-a-call-to-pause-error)
link also has the same discussion.